# How to solve error "Coordinate should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form"

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot an arrow in the direction of the gradient. This is my code:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.07], 
 Arrow[Tube[{{x0, y0, 
     F[x0, y0]}, {{x0, y0, F[x0, y0]} + gradF[x0, y0, F[x0, y0]]/
      Norm[gradF[x0, y0, F[x0, y0]]]}, {{x0, y0, F[x0, y0]} + 
      gradF[x0, y0, F[x0, y0]]/Norm[gradF[x0, y0, F[x0, y0]]]}}, 
   0.05]]}]
```

However, i am getting the error on the description. I am trying to solve it but i am not able to. 
This is gradF

```
gradF[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[F1[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

and this is F1

```
F1[x_, y_, z_] := F[x, y] - z;
```

this is F

```
F[x_, y_] := -( x^2 + y^2);
```

I am trying to understand exactly why i am getting that error so i can solve it my self in the future. Let me know if you need more details of the code.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `x0` and `y0` need to be numbers, and you have two many {} around the second and third elements of the `Tube`. Look at the InputForm of your expression.

Comment: @CarlWoll This is inside a Manipulate and x0 and y0 are the parameters that i manipulate. Does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, look at the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) of the graphics:

```
With[{x0=1,y0=1},
    Graphics3D[{
        Red,Arrowheads[0.07],
        Arrow[Tube[
            {
            {x0,y0,F[x0,y0]},
            {{x0,y0,F[x0,y0]}+gradF[x0,y0,F[x0,y0]]/Norm[gradF[x0,y0,F[x0,y0]]]},
            {{x0,y0,F[x0,y0]}+gradF[x0,y0,F[x0,y0]]/Norm[gradF[x0,y0,F[x0,y0]]]}
            },
            0.05
        ]]
    }]
]//InputForm
```

> Graphics3D[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Arrowheads[0.07], 
>     Arrow[Tube[{{1, 1, -2}, {{1/3, 1/3, -7/3}}, {{1/3, 1/3, -7/3}}}, 0.05]]}]

You should see that the second and third elements of the argument to [`Tube`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube) have an extra `{}` around them. If you remove these extra braces, you will have:

```
With[{x0=1,y0=1},
    Graphics3D[{
        Red,Arrowheads[0.07],
        Arrow[Tube[
            {
            {x0,y0,F[x0,y0]},
            {x0,y0,F[x0,y0]}+gradF[x0,y0,F[x0,y0]]/Norm[gradF[x0,y0,F[x0,y0]]],
            {x0,y0,F[x0,y0]}+gradF[x0,y0,F[x0,y0]]/Norm[gradF[x0,y0,F[x0,y0]]]
            },
            0.05
        ]]
    }]
]
```

The above produces a valid [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D) object.